# Wrong tensorflow version used after !pip install tf-nightly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm using some code written by my lecturer & I'm running it on a GPU in Google Colab. At the beginning of the code the tf-nightly package is installed using `!pip install tf-nightly`. Afterwards, the following packages are imported and the version of tf used is printed out as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np

import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

print(tf.__version__)
```

For some reason, sometimes the version of tf used isn't always 2.3.xxx but instead sometimes it's 2.2 - but not always. Usually this happens when the tab has been open for a while but I haven't been using it.

This then causes the error

"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing' has no attribute 'image_dataset_from_directory'" when I try to use this package.

Can anyone tell me how to stop this from happening/what to do if it does happen?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you note the 2.3.XXX version and then use !pip install tf-nightly==2.3.XXX ?

Comment: This is currently working, thank you! I hope it won't be as unstable as the other way. If anyone knows why without specifying the version it sometimes randomly stops installing the 2.3.xxx version I'd be very grateful to know for future reference!

Comment: I guess it's because not all Colab are running on the same system. So when you start a Colab session, pip version on the machine could be different? Not sure though